# How can i create substrings from given strings in python?

Tags: python, regex

Hi how can I create substrings from following strings

```
Netall_Low_Lin_kor_110_180
Netall_Low_Lin_cer_110_181
Netall_Low_Lin_asa_110_182
Netall_Low_Lin_row_110_183
Netall_Low_Lin_psq_182_42
Netall_Low_Lin_vyt_182_41
```

I want to split the above strings in such a way that "Netall_Low_Lin_kor" will be one part and "110_180" will be another part. And for "Netall_Low_Lin_psq_182_42" I want to split it into "Netall_Low_Lin_psq" and "182_42".

Is there any way to split these strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list_of_strings = [
"Netall_Low_Lin_kor_110_180",
"Netall_Low_Lin_cer_110_181",
"Netall_Low_Lin_asa_110_182",
"Netall_Low_Lin_row_110_183",
"Netall_Low_Lin_psq_182_42",
"Netall_Low_Lin_vyt_182_41"
]

import re
pattern = re.compile("_(?=\d+_\d+)")
for current_string in list_of_strings:
    print pattern.split(current_string)
```

**Output**

```
['Netall_Low_Lin_kor', '110_180']
['Netall_Low_Lin_cer', '110_181']
['Netall_Low_Lin_asa', '110_182']
['Netall_Low_Lin_row', '110_183']
['Netall_Low_Lin_psq', '182_42']
['Netall_Low_Lin_vyt', '182_41']
```

[RegEx101 Demo + Explanation](http://regex101.com/r/xQ6wT9)

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use regular expressions if the substrings are of fixed size, using slices is much simpler in this case:

```
s = 'Netall_Low_Lin_kor_110_180'
s[:18]
=>  Netall_Low_Lin_kor
s[19:]
=> 110_180
```